# Use Trello as data Source for website and mobile App.How to Implement trello in server side because using apiKey and Token to client side in not good

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, trello, trello-powerup

I am using trello.I can call Trello Rest Api with APIKEY and TOKEN from my website using jQuery, get JSON and show into HTML page.This is not good to share KEY and TOKEN.I want to implement Trello in my Node.js backend server to server trello data to website.What should I do.?

Answer (score 0):

All i did was writing `nodejs trello` in google and the first answer was this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-trello

the second result was this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/trello